# system property to check whether instance is backend?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Which system property key that can be used to check whether instance is a frontend or backend ?

```
SystemProperty.**
```

Comment: refer to [System Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

Comment: dude, this is for appengine. there is no key for that i already refer api

Comment: LOL! didnt see the tag, my bad. good luck then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current set of Environment properties that you can access in your App Engine application is given over [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#Java_The_environment). I don't think there is a property that refers to what you are trying to get.

However, I would suggest that you print out the request headers in the incoming request object, there could be something that could give you the hint there:

```
Enumeration headers = req.getHeaderNames();
while (headers.hasMoreElements()) {
    String name = (String)headers.nextElement();
    String value = req.getHeader(name);
    resp.getWriter().println(String.format("%s: %s", name, value));
}
```

Additionally, I would suggest to look at the Backend API. This should give values of particular interest to you too: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/backends/BackendService